# Redux testing with nock data undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, nock

I am using node nock to test my redux async action. The test is currently failing with the output :

```
AssertionError: expected [ Array(2) ] to deeply equal [ Array(2) ]
      + expected - actual

         {
           "type": "FETCH_MOVIES"
         }
         {
      -    "data": [undefined]
      +    "data": [
      +      {
      +        "title": "Batman vs Superman"
      +      }
      +    ]
           "type": "FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS"
         }
       ]
```

actions.js :

```
import axios from 'axios';

import * as constants from '../constants/constants';

const MOVIES_API = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=xxx';

function fetchMoviesRequest() {
  return {
    type: constants.FETCH_MOVIES
  };
}

function fetchMoviesSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: constants.FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS,
    data
  };
}

function fetchMoviesError(ex) {
  return {
    type: constants.FETCH_MOVIES_ERROR,
    ex
  };
}

export function fetchMovies() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchMoviesRequest());
    return axios.get(MOVIES_API)
      .then(res => dispatch(fetchMoviesSuccess(res.data.results)))
      .catch(ex => dispatch(fetchMoviesError(ex)));
  };
}
```

actions.spec.js :

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from './actions';
import * as ActionTypes from '../constants/constants';
import nock from 'nock';
import { expect } from 'chai';

const MOVIES_API = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=xxx';
const middlewares = [ thunk ];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

describe('async actions', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    nock.cleanAll();
  });

  it('creates FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS when fetching movies is complete', () => {
    nock(MOVIES_API)
      .log(console.log)
      .get('/')
      .reply(200, {data: {results: [{title: 'Batman vs Superman'}]}});

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: ActionTypes.FETCH_MOVIES },
      { type: ActionTypes.FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCESS, data: {results: [{title: 'Batman vs Superman'}]}}
    ];

    // const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));
    const store = mockStore( { movies: {} });

    return store.dispatch(actions.fetchMovies()).then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).to.deep.equal(expectedActions);
      });
  });
});
```

This is my first time using nock so I'm not sure what I need to do to get the data to be defined.

Comment: When you hit `GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=xxx/` in your browser, do you get an object with a top-level `data` key?

Comment: @MarioTacke no. The beginning of the data looks like : `{"page":1,"results":[{"poster_path":"\/cGOPbv9wA5gEejkUN892JrveARt.jpg","adult":false,"overview":"Fearing the actions of a god-like Super Hero`